# Where I can get the full list of San Francisco Bay Area Tech Companies?

Tags: geospatial, openstreetmap

There already a [SiliconValleyMap](https://www.siliconvalleymap.org/), but I want to create a San Francisco Bay Area Tech Companies Map. Where I can find the company list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many Bay area companies are included in the [SV map](https://www.siliconvalleymap.org/), despite its name.

You can access the [raw data as a json](https://www.siliconvalleymap.org/placemarks.json) ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20190414094752/https://www.siliconvalleymap.org/placemarks.json))

Data model looks as follows:

```
  {
    "marketValuation": 0,
    "title": "Docker",
    "wealthfront": false,
    "imageUrl": "https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=docker.com",
    "longitude": -122.391933,
    "isPublic": false,
    "latitude": 37.780346,
    "startupValuation": 1
  },
```

[image]

Comment: +1000 for the wayback machine save

Answer (score 1):

Here is an open source list via Github with the information you are looking for. 
https://github.com/connor11528/companies-in-the-bay-area